# Change Blender 2.8 theme?

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I installed Blender 2.80 Beta on my PC and the UI looks different from what it should (as I find online, and having tested it on a friend's computer). The boxes have a weird gradient-like active status which I don't like:

[image]

How can I get the default theme with flat input boxes?

(+[screenshot of my entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmrA.png))

Answer (score 1):

*Edit* > *Preferences* > *Themes* > *Reset to Default theme* > *Save Preferences*

[image]

(after entering the "*Themes*" tab you might need to load "*Dark Blender*" from the *Presets*)

Comment: No, doing that does not do anything

Comment: @TomHancy You mean that you've done that and you still have these little gradients in the sliders on a fresh file? I see that your file is vastly customized (the viewport's header is a footer, you have non-default workspaces etc) so please test resetting the preferences on a fresh file first

Comment: I don't get it. Could you be clearer?

Comment: if you start blender, with a blank file (default cube etc), and follow my instructions in the Answer, does it still not work? do you still see the gradients on the buttons?

Comment: I think it is a problem with Windows 8.

Comment: i don't think every win8 user is experiencing the same. Have you tried starting blender with a blank file and following the instructions? Are you using an updated version of the Beta?

Comment: I had it installed on a Windows 10 PC where it worked just fine - mine is Windows 8. I copied the setup file after finding a problem with the downloaded version and the error persisted - which is why I assumed that it is an OS problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if you have tried my answer at all at this point. Fine anyway, glad you are ok now.